# HCE service and BIND_NFC_SERVICE permission

Tags: android, permissions, nfc, android-permissions, hce

First of all I'm fairly new to programming Android apps. My programing language is Java. I searched for a solution on the web and asked other programmers with no solution.

**Situation:**
I have developed an application that uses the HCE service. This application is triggered by another device and data is transferred using ISO 7816-4 APDU commands. Everything is working as expected and the app is selected using an AID.

**Problem:**
The app was developed on a *NEXUS 4* with *Android 5.1.1* running. By the time I got newer NFC enabled phones on my desk to test the app. 
All of them are Android 6 or newer. Non of them is working with my app. It seems that the permission *BIND_NFC_SERVICE* is not granted. Since the way permissions are handled changed since Android 5 to 6 update I implemented the new method mentioned by [Android developer request app permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) (I also checked the related posts here). The permission is just denied with no further information. On the NFC interface the APDU trying to select the app by its AID is returned with *6999* meaning the operation is not allowed.

On a rooted phone I can see that the permission is denied and I tried to grant it manually. But after every start of the app it is denied again and the app can never use it.

Seems like the HCE service itself has to ask for the permission, but how?

Below you can find my AndroidManifest.xml and the build.gradle. I also tried to change to a higher API level.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.XXXXXXXX.hce_tests">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyHostApduService"  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".AutoTuneInterface"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.XXXXXXXX.hce_tests"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':GraphView')
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

#### BIND_NFC_SERVICE Permission

You are not supposed to request the permission `BIND_NFC_SERVICE` from your app. This permission is reserved for the NFC system service and this service should be the only application that holds that permission.

Instead, your app needs to enforce this permission when an application tries to *bind to* your HCE service component. You already do that with

```
<service android:name=".MyHostApduService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE"
```

That way, Android prevents injection of APDUs into your HCE service by other (malicious) apps, since no (malicious) app could bind to your HCE service.

#### Error 6999

Why Android does not detect your HCE service and returns 6999 to indicate that the AID was not found, is a trickier question. I could think of a few reasons:

- Your service is not explicitly marked as exported (add the attribute `android:exported="true"` to the service component). However, this should not matter since the HCE service also declares an intent filter which implicitly sets the exported attribute true.
- If your app is flagged as a payment app (in apduservice.xml), you will need to make sure that it is the selected payment app ("Tap & pay" in the Settings app).
- Some devices do not seem to support HCE and a secure element in parallel and have a switch to choose between the secure element and HCE somewhere in the Settings app (probably also within the Tap & pay settings).

Comment: Very good to know, that one does not need to ask for that permission. I added the 'android:exported="true"' statement in the manifest file with no effect. My App is not flagged as a payment app and is not listed as such in the settings of the devices. I searched for the option regarding the secure element without success. Since I noticed [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce) changed on April 24th I gave up and created a complete new test application (also the code doesn't seem to differ). Also this made no changes or success.

Comment: @engineer0815 You may still want to post the contents of your apduservice.xml file here.

Comment: of course sorry: `<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/servicedesc"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
    <aid-group android:description="@string/aiddescription"
        android:category="other">
        <aid-filter android:name="F0010203040506"/>
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>`

Comment: You did try to communicate with your HCE service while the device was unlocked and no application was in the foreground, right?

Comment: Yes and as I wrote it is allready working on an Android 5 device. This is the reason why I thought about a permissions problem in the first place.